# How to fetch text values from TextViews, convert them into integers and manipulate them programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val B:Button=findViewById(R.id.convert)
    val a:EditText= findViewById(R.id.m)
    val b:TextView= findViewById(R.id.cm)
    B.setOnClickListener{convert(a,b)}
}
private fun convert(a:EditText,b:TextView){
    var fg=a.text
    b.visibility=VISIBLE
    b.text=fg
}
```

}

I am trying to get the text from EditText and i want to change that number and then want to display through text view

Answer (score 0):

```
var addedValue=a.text.toString().toInt() + 10 // here your value
b.visibility=VISIBLE
b.text=addedValue.toString()
```

Comment: Why we are using toString() here

Comment: `a.text` returns a CharSequence. You need a String to be able to use `toInt()`.